# How to implement GET method getById in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not getting data from backend for my method GET byId. Other methods as getAll(), for example, are working. So i think the problem in code/syntax of Component.

My Component:

```
class Account extends Component {
    accountItem = {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        link: ''
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            item: this.accountItem
        };
        this.reloadAccount = this.reloadAccount.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.reloadAccount();
    }

    reloadAccount(id) {
        ApiService.fetchAccountById(id)
            .then((res) => {
                let account = res.data;
                this.setState({
                    id: account.id,
                    name: account.name,
                    email: account.email,
                    password: account.password,
                    link: account.link
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        const {item} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className={c.account}>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Id: {item.id}</li>
                        <li>Name: {item.name}</li>
                        <li>Email: {item.email}</li>
                        <li>Password: {item.password}</li>
                        <li>Link: {item.link}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

ApiService:

```
fetchAccountById(id) {
        return axios.get(ACCOUNT_API_BASE_URL + '/' + id);
    }
```

My backend api: "/api/accounts/{id}"
I am getting:

```
"http://localhost:8080/api/accounts/undefined 400"
```

What problem could be?
I have deleted 'result' from res.data.result, but it still not works(for getAll method worked for me)

Comment: please share what error you get

Comment: @behzad the problem is about error parsing String to Long in backend.
So on frontend i am not correctly sending data, I guess.
Backend gets "undefined"

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/api/accounts/undefined` means that `id` is undefined. This is correct since it looks like you forgot to pass in the `id` when you call `this.reloadAccount` in `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are calling `this.reloadAccount()` in `componentDidMount()`, you are not passing the `id` due to which the `id` in `fetchAccountById` is undefined and thus you are not able to fetch the data.

Comment: So how I should pass it?

Comment: componentDidMount() {this.reloadAccount(this.id); }
 like that doesnt work

Comment: it depends on where you are getting `id` from. `this.id` doesn't work because it doesn't exist. you should tell us, what should `id` be?

Comment: i fixed by editing Route to='../:id' and reloadAccount method put into item {} object